# Calculating the mean of compass directions which cross 360/ 0 degrees

Tags: r, mean, directions

Given a data set of compass directions like this:

```
A<-c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)
CompDir<-c(350,358,355,358,2,356,180,173,170,2,3,359)

DF<-data.frame(A,CompDir)
```

If I want to take an average by group:

```
aggregate(DF[,2],list(DF$A),mean)
```

I run into trouble when I cross the 360/ 0 threshold.

```
  Group.1        x
1       1 354.3333
2       2 238.6667
3       3 174.3333
4       4 121.3333
```

The means for groups 2 and 4 are incorrect, so how do you correctly calculate means for this kind of directional data?

Comment: see the `circular` or `CircularStats` package.  Basically, you have to compute the x and y (sin/cos) components, average them, and then compute the direction (arc-tangent).

Comment: And of course, there's an (albeit short) [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_of_circular_quantities), where @BenBolker 's suggestion is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the mean of `sin` and `cos`, then use `atan2` to get the direction.
As the functions are calculating in radians the given directions need to converted by first dividing and then multiplying by 180 and pi.

```
tt <- aggregate(cbind(x = sin(DF$CompDir/180*pi), y = cos(DF$CompDir/180*pi)), DF["A"], mean)
cbind(tt[1], CompDir = (atan2(tt$x, tt$y)/pi*180) %% 360)
#  A    CompDir
#1 1 354.333872
#2 2 358.666366
#3 3 174.331668
#4 4   1.333465
```

Answer (score 1):

I thin you can try the complex numbers to compute the `mean`, e.g.,

```
aggregate(
    . ~ A,
    transform(
        DF,
        CompDir = exp(1i * CompDir * pi / 180)
    ),
    \(x) (Arg(mean(x)) * 180 / pi) %% 360
)
```

and you will obtain

```
  A    CompDir
1 1 354.333872
2 2 358.666366
3 3 174.331668
4 4   1.333465
```